AntD Select components share the same state
I'm creating a React project in which i use Select component from AntD. My code now looks like this:
import { Tabs } from "antd"
import type { TabsProps } from 'antd';
import { useAppSelector } from "../../store/hooks";
import { Properties } from "../../types/types";
import { SelectComponent } from "../Select/Select";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`
const Text = styled.p`
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
`

export const TreeOptions = () => {
    const { itemProperties }: { itemProperties: Properties[] | [] } = useAppSelector(state => state.tree)

    const items: TabsProps['items'] = itemProperties.map((item, i) => ({
        key: item.id,
        label: item.tabname,
        children: item.editable !== true ?
            <Container>
                {item.options.map((option, i) => <Text key={i}>{option}</Text>)}
            </Container> :
            <Container>
                <SelectComponent options={item} />  // here is my select
            </Container>
    }))

    return <Tabs items={items} />
}

The Select component itself looks like this:
import { Select } from "antd"
import { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)`
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
`

export const SelectComponent = (options: any) => {
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined)  // this state belongs to every select

    return (
        <StyledSelect  
            value={selectedValue} 
            options={options.options.options.map((item: string) => ({ value: item, label: item }))}
        />
    )
}

For some reason (I can not understand why) all of my selects share one single state for all of them. Can somebody explain to me why? I tried using keys while mapping but it didn't help me. 
I'll leave my full code here

Did you make sure that your item ids are unique?

@Kn3cht, I feel myself stupid now. Thanks, it works just fine now
